# io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: The 'ImportantCalls' class is missing from the schema for this Realm?

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I am facing the issue in realm migration. I want to add the new model class in a realm database. Please help me how to solve this.

```
    public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        if (oldVersion==0){

            oldVersion ++;
        }

        if (oldVersion == 1) {

            schema.create("ImportantCalls")
                    .addField("id", int.class)
                    .addField("number", String.class)
                    .addField("callType", String.class)
                    .addField("startTime", String.class)
                    .addField("callRecords", String.class)
                    .addField("callStatus", String.class)
                    .addField("actualStartTime", Long.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 37;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof Migration);
    }
}
```

The above code is for the migrating the realm.

The below code is my realm iitializing in oncreate() method in android

```
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
        Realm.init(this);
//        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
//                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
//                .build();
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .schemaVersion(5) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
                .migration(new Migration()) // Migration to run
                .build();

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
//        Realm.deleteRealm(config);
        realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

The exception is occurring in the `realm.getDefaultInstance(); in this line.`

Before doing migration i deleted the data in realm database by ` Realm.deleteRealm(config);

but actually it is not a good practice so i tried to migrating the data. Please help me how to solve this.`

Comment: Your migration is saying v5, but in your code, you add the class at v1. What is happening in 2-5?

Comment: @ Christian Melchior  what i want to change in my code

Comment: @PrabhaKaran You need migration steps for version 2 to 5?

Answer (score 0):

First, clean project and rebuild it. Then, check if your database doesn't exist but you get it and display to UI. Use RealmObject.isValid() to check it. For example:

```
 mInteractor.getOneDayData(dayOfWeek, new Repositories.Callback<OneDay>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(OneDay item) {
            if (item.isValid()) { // please check if item is valid before you use it
                //udpate ui

            } else {
                mView.showToast("No data");
            }
        }

    });
```